# Convert RDD[Key,List[Value]] into RDD with pairs [Key,ValueFromList1],[Key,ValueFromList2]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and transformation, so need a little help. I've managed to find reversed solution. when you make a value into a list and ot from. I want to "flatten" I guess the value of the key. I have a RDD like Map where Key is Int and value is List of Strings. I need to make pairs with Key and each Value in list into one RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap and then map each element to a tuple like so

```
val flattenedRDD = pairRDD.flatMap { case (i,l)  => l.map( l => (i,l)) }
```

Comment: Hey Mike, the solution you've provided should have worked. But now I have problems with casting.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Is there a possibility to properly cast in flat map rows?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd have to see your code at least when it's failling

Comment: Im not convinced the datatype is what you say it is anymore.  If you post your snippet I can help you

Comment: `//loading into data frame
val matchesRDD = MongoSpark.load[Match](spark, readConfig)

//making DF [Boolean,Seq[Player]]
val tuplesArrayIGuess = matchesRDD
      .rdd
      .map(elem => {(elem.getAs[Boolean]("radiantWin"), elem.getAs[Seq[PlayerMongo]]("players"))})

//and code you've suggested. it's failing on case line.
    tuplesArrayIGuess.flatMap({
      case (i,l)  => l.map( l => (i,l))
    })`
Hope this will help. Sorry about editing style. could not do in any other way in comment section

Comment: Found the problem(I guess). This casting is not working when getting value from fields by name, but works perfectly by index. Thanks @mike for your help